# Enviar uma tabela usando pacote Teamr em R

Tags: r

Estou desenvolvendo uma rotina em R para enviar atualização de dados para os usuários de um grupo do MS Teams usando o pacote Teamr. A dificuldade surge na formatação das mensagens...

```
library(teamr)
canal = "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/00487f9d..."
con <- connector_card$new(hookurl = canal )
con$title("Título")
con$text("Corpo")
con$send()
```

O resultado...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, o "Corpo" precisa estar formatado internamente até mesmo para CR-LF.

```
con$title("Título")
con$text(
  paste("Linha1","Linha2","Linha3","Linha4", sep = "<br>"))
con$send()
```

O resultado...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso precise usar tabelas, tenho que fazer strings com `<tr><td></td></tr>`. O código vira um pesadelo.

Pergunta: existe algum pacote/função/jeito para gerar strings HTML de uma forma mais fácil?

Comment: O pacote [xtable](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=xtable) permite exportar tabelas para o formato HTML.